# while i create a newLine Character in XML while usinfg SAXTransformerHandler..i get some special characters

Tags: xml, rhapsody

```
<Test_Node>test</Test_Node>
<description>Responsible Architect:&#xD;
**&#xD;
Joerg Cunz, CES for CSW&#xD;
Christian Sussmann, CES for DDS&#xD;
Dirk Froehlich CHS, for EPB&#xD;
&#xD;
Rationale:&#xD;
&#xD;
</description>**
```

When I generate the above `<description>`  node in the xml file using SAXTransformerFactory in java.. I found the some special characters(&#xD) at the end of every line.. may I know how to avoid it. Also the codes which generated the xml file is as follows: JAVA CODE used*

```
 >SAXTransformerFactory tf = (SAXTransformerFactory)      SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance();
  xmlHandler = tf.newTransformerHandler();
  Transformer serializer = xmlHandler.getTransformer();
   serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "ISO-8895-1"); 
   serializer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
  //serializer.setOutputProperties();
   xmlHandler.setResult(streamResult);
   xmlHandler.startDocument();**
```